# Yii2: How to show less lines on all rows of a Gridview?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-grid

I have a Gridview with three columns. The **Query** column is a **PostgreSQL TEXT** type and has 9 lines in this example.

I would like to show only the first 4 lines for all rows else my table will be too big.

[image: An example of the table]

Comment: are you looking for a css based option?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam: Yes, good idea.

Comment: you can use the `ellipses` property to control the height and display the required number of lines for using the `css` based option.

Answer (score 1):

**Display text based on the number of specified lines.**
Assuming that the text in the DB with 
 Saved. too \n

*You do it according to the necessary separator....* `<br>` or `<p>` ...

```
// Attribute name: text
[
    'attribute' => 'text',
    'format' => 'html',
    'value' => function ($model) {
         $array= array_chunk(explode('<br>', nl2br($model->text)),4);
         return implode("<br>",$array[0]);
    },
],
```

**Display text based on the number of specified characters**

```
[
    'attribute' => 'text',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        // without breaking the word
        return mb_substr($model->text,0,strpos($model->text, ' ', 400));
       // by breaking the word
        return mb_substr($model->text, 0, 400, mb_detect_encoding($model->text))." ...";
    },
],
```

**Display text based on element width. max-width**

```
[
    'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 25vw; overflow: hidden;'],
    'attribute' => 'text',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return $model->text;
    },
],
```

**display Text based on height**

*Note: Change the height according to your font and requirements.*

```
 [
        'format' => 'raw',
        'attribute' => 'text',
        'value' => function ($model) {
            return '<div style="line-height: 1.2em; height: 4.8em; overflow: hidden;">'.\yii\helpers\HtmlPurifier::process($model->text).'</div>';
        },
    ],
```

Comment: i would prefer the ellipses but not varying the `width` BUT the `height` as the requirements

Comment: I added another item. I hope you help. Good luck.